# How to get first printable html element using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to print first printable html element using JS, how can I do it?

Example 1:

```
<b>THIS</b>
<div>foo<div>
```

expected: `<b>THIS</b>`

Example 2:

```
<body>
<b>THIS</b>
<div>foo<div>
</body>
```

expected: `<b>THIS</b>`

Example 3:

```
<html>
<body>
<b>THIS</b>
<div>foo<div>
</body>
</html>
```

expected: `<b>THIS</b>`

Example 4:

```
<b>THIS</b>
<html>
<body> 
<div>foo<div>
</body>
</html>
```

expected: `<b>THIS</b>`
(I know that is not really valid html, but on the other way is valid ...)

Example 5:

```
<html>
<style>
body {...}
</style>
<body> 
<b>THIS</b>
<div>foo<div>
</body>
</html>
```

expected: `<b>THIS</b>`

Note:
I am ignoring `css, display none, etc`..

I don't know which code should I use.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

- Loop through all elements on the page excluding style elements
- Remove all their children but preserve text by removing their `lastElementChild` in a `while` loop
- Getting the element `textContent`. If, after trimming, the length is greater than 0, we know the element is "printable", so we assign it to `found` and print it after the loop.

```js
var found = null;
document.querySelectorAll("*:not(style)").forEach((e) => {
  const clone = e.cloneNode(true);
  while (clone.lastElementChild) {
    clone.removeChild(clone.lastElementChild);
  }
  if (clone.textContent.trim().length > 0 && found == null) {
    found = e;
  }
})
console.log(found);
```

```html
<html>
<style>
  body {
    ...
  }
</style>

<body>
  <b>THIS</b>
  <div>foo</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @ziatob No problem :)